# Knockout Durandal compose view $root access

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel, root, durandal

I am using Hot SPA template (which uses knockout and durandal) to display something on screen.
My html code is getting very long so I'm trying to split and dice it into smaller reusable components.

The code renders find and shows everything I expect it to. But I seem to have lost the handle to the main viewmodel

From my main view, I tried to

```
<!-- ko if: A -->
<!--ko compose: { model: $data, view: '../tmpl/A'} -->
<!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```

In my tmpl/A.html file, I have the following:

```
         <!-- ko foreach: array -->
            <!--ko compose: { model: $data, view: '../tmpl/tmpl1'} -->
            <!--/ko-->
            <!--/ko-->
```

Now from within /tmpl/tmpl1 I tried to bind a button to my model
    Do something

It does nothing at all.
It appears from within /tmpl/tmpl1 I can only see the array item. 
I tried to print out

```
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></div>
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div>
```

both only shows the array item.

Please advise what I can do.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting a JavaScript error?  ko.toJSON($root) should produce a circular reference.

Comment: I removed 'model: $data' from the ko compose, and now the parent context flows through. Case solved.

Comment: when using <!--ko compose: .. --> you have to watch out for one thing.
Durandal may fiddle with the first div to make it a wrapper.
So you generally should make your own div wrapper without any bindings:  
 <div>
  <div data-bind=""..............
 </div>

Answer (score 0):

How to inspect your full $root values if all of these kinds are observables and your javascript convert cant be accessed inside?
Solution:

```
for (var element in ko.contextFor($0).$root) {
    if (ko.contextFor($0).$root.hasOwnProperty(element)) {
        console.info(element + ": ") 
        console.info(ko.toJS(ko.contextFor($0).$root[element])) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it answer to OP question? Could you add some explanation how your code solves original question (not the one you introduced)?